# How to map depends on height of content?

Tags: jquery, css

I have left and right side... on left side I have some list of something and on right side I have Google Map. I need that map is 100% height so that depends on height of left content. http://jsfiddle.net/3r7r1zkq/11/ this is my fiddle, CSS for map is last. Any suggestion? I tried to put height:100% on parent element but maps is not appear, until I put some height in `px`.

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Kindly put your full code in the question, *if possible*.

Comment: i put my fiddle, code is too long to put it here

Comment: so @PraveenKumar any suggestion? :)

Comment: Positioning would help. But Google Maps is not working with positions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but you could try to make the #map_canvas positioning fixed (so it scrolls with the user) and assign a height with vh (viewport height).

Comment: if i have a lot things on left side so that user need to scroll them i want that  map on right spread also

Comment: I understand but you can assign a width then as well of 50% so it scrolls with the user (as he/she scrolls down) only on the right side.

Comment: im using bootstrap so map width is 100% of col-md-6 so that is 50%